# Error with finding angles based off x and y axis in LWJGL

Tags: eclipse, 2d, lwjgl, angle

I'm writing a program in LWJGL and I've made a basic x and y axis with doubles, I tried making a function to calculate the angle of the mouse(black box) relative to the user (grey box). It works well but for some reason the angles only go from 0 to 90 to 0 to negative 90 and back to 0.

http://imgur.com/a/n6Bm7#0

Here's an imgur album illustrating my problem

Here's my code for the function

```
public double calcAngle(double x, double y) {
        //double DEG2RAD = 0.0174532925;
        double RAD2DEG = 57.2957795;
        double h = Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2);
        h = Math.pow(h, 0.5);
        double z = y / h;
        z = Math.asin(z);
        z = z * RAD2DEG;
        return z;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that Math.asin returns a value between -90 < x < 90 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

To solve this you can add some logic to see if the x coordinate is negative. In case of a negative x you have to do "return 180 - z" instead of just "return z"

This would give you an angle range of -90 < x < 270.